# Spring Security auto logout for particular user after timeout using thread from Java class

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-security, logout

I have a problem. I can't implement user's Spring Security auto logout for particular user after timeout using thread.
I've already tried to implement the kill of the particular user's session. Also I've already tried to call Spring Security logout from my thread. 
Here is my implementing of user's session kill.

```
public class Logout {

    private static HttpServletRequest request;
    private static HttpServletResponse response;


    public static void threadrun() {

        Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                        HttpSession newsession = request.getSession(false);

                        if (newsession != null) {
                            newsession.invalidate();
                        }
                        // I want to kill session for particular user, but don't know how

                        response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp");

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```